# What type of wood should I use as an outdoor table top for a BBQ?

Tags: wood, brick, outdoor

I am going to build a brick BBQ similar to something like the below BBQ picture.

The position will be against the house and will get wet from rain. I only plan to cover the BBQ.

Would I be ok to have a wooden counter top?

What types of wood should I look at?

How to protect?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend something that is dimensionally stable, resistant to rot and easy to work, like cherry, chestnut or walnut - for an outdoor food preparation surface, any tight-grained hardwood will work. (See also the ["Wood Picker"](http://www.woodbin.com/calcs/wdpick.htm) app)

Fine woodwork that's meant to be kept exposed to the elements should be protected with a marine-grade spar varnish. This requires a bit more effort and care to apply, and will require periodic maintenance - google "brightwork", which is the art of applying finish to wooden structures on boats. There have been entire books written on the topic, but [here's an article to get you started.](http://www.allatsea.net/caribbean/maintaining-your-brightwork-with-good-old-spar-varnish/)

Comment: wow what a link the wood picker is. I edited your post to correct the link too.

Comment: excellent second article too.